# Missing property @ViewChildren

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

I'm a beginner in Angular and I would like to receive some help for a problem that understand the origin but I don't know how to resolve. So I would like to receive some help please. First of all here is a picture of my scr folder:

[image]

My errors is located in my upgrade.component.ts, which is:

```
export class UpgradeComponent implements OnInit {
  canclose=false;
  @Input() upgrade: Pallier[];
  server = "http://localhost:8080/";
  @Input() world: World;
  @Input() money: number;

  @Output() closemodalevent = new EventEmitter<void>();

  constructor(private snackBar: MatSnackBar, private service: RestserviceService) { 

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  popMessage(message: string) : void {
    this.snackBar.open(message, "", {duration : 2000});
  }

  closemodal(){
    if(this.canclose){
      this.closemodalevent.emit();
    }else{
      this.canclose=true;
    }
  }

  purchaseUpgrade(p: Pallier) {
    if (this.world.money > p.seuil) {
      this.world.money = this.world.money - p.seuil;
      this.world.upgrades.pallier[this.world.upgrades.pallier.indexOf(p)].unlocked = true;
      this.popMessage("Achat d'une upgrade de" +p.typeratio);
      if (p.idcible == 0) {
        this.productsComponent.forEach(prod => prod.calcUpgrade(p));
        this.popMessage("Achat d'une upgrade de ");
      }
      else {
        this.productsComponent.forEach(prod => {
          if (p.idcible == prod.product.id) {
            prod.calcUpgrade(p);
            this.popMessage("Achat d'une upgrade de " +p.typeratio);
          }
        })
      }
      this.service.putUpgrade(p);
    }
  }
}
```

The error is a simple:

Property 'productsComponent' does not exist on type 'UpgradeComponent'.

The problem is not that this property is located at app.component.ts, but that is a @ViewChildren.Here is my app.component.ts:

```
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChildren(ProductComponent) public productsComponent: QueryList<ProductComponent>;
  title = 'AngularProject';
  world: World = new World();
  server: String;
  username: string;
  qtmulti = "x1";
  modal: string=null;

  constructor(private service: RestserviceService, public snackBar: MatSnackBar) {
    this.server = service.getServer();
    this.username = localStorage.getItem("username");
    // Fonction créant un nom de joueur aléatoire si le nom du joueur est et qui sera sauverarder dans le serveur
    if (this.username == '') {
      this.username = 'Player' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
      localStorage.setItem("username", this.username);
    }
    this.service.setUser(this.username);
    service.getWorld().then(world => { this.world = world; });
  }

  popMessage(m: string) : void {
    this.snackBar.open(m, "", { duration: 2000 });
  }
}
```

And I absolutly can't find anything on the web and I have no idea how to resolve this error...

I thanks in advance anybody who would be kind enough to enlight me.

Comment: why are you using ViewChildren first of all?

Comment: In order for the parent warn all children (product) when I there is an unlock

Comment: what is the version of angular

Comment: @malbarmavi Angular 9

Comment: If your issue resolved, kindly accept the answer which helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The @ViewChildren decorator works only inside the component you are working and it finds just for the html components you are calling inside its html template.

```js
export class AppComponent {
    @ViewChildren(ProductComponent) public productsComponent: QueryList<ProductComponent>;
}
```

then in app template

```html
<product-component #p1></product-component>
<product-component #p2></product-component>
<product-component #p3></product-component>
```

In your case, you should declare the @ViewChildren in the upgrade component and in its html template call all the products components as html tag.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to refer `ProductComponent` inside `UpgradeComponent`. But you didn't called 
`ProductComponent` in your `UpgradeComponent`. `this` in UpgradeComponent will refer to the Properties and methods which are declared in UpgradeComponent. Thats why you are getting error `Property 'productsComponent' does not exist on type 'UpgradeComponent'.` To access other component data you can use `Input / Output decorator , Passing the reference of one component to another, service or @ViewChild/ @ViewChildren`. 
This Blog will help you https://medium.com/@mirokoczka/3-ways-to-communicate-between-angular-components-a1e3f3304ecb